# Android XML Animation horribly lags on bigger images

Tags: android, animation

I encounter a problem to which i got no answer to google at all. So i got an image which is `740x610` pixels, 282.73kb, 32bit color.I simply apply the simplest rotation animation upon this image, thats how the boss wants.The xml code for animation is the next.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <rotate
        android:duration="5000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

this is how i apply animation inside the code.(The target to be animated is an ImageView)

```
levelUpLightingRight.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotate_right));
```

Anyways, whenever the animation starts rotation lagging the worst way it could be. I tried to make image smaller, and BOOM, that worked, the animation is never being smoother. Problems are the next. I can't resize image no way,because if i do so,image get rectangle around it and its ugly,so the designer made it look right so i stuck up with this image size. Animation applied to this image lagging. I can't make image smaller because that won't be as boss wants the UI to be seen so i stuck in the point where animation purely lags like i never seen before in my development experience. What i tried so far.

1-applying required parameters to manifest.xml like ...`android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`,`android:largeHeap="true"`
2-Trying with different types of animations like `ValueAnimatior`,`ObjectAnimator`,`AnimatorSet` and so on.
3-Using third part libraries like 2d renderings.
Ofcourse nothing helped me out.Im thinking of applying animation inside surface view,but i don't see it coming to success..Anyway if anyone encounter such problems and do have solution,please share,or at least guide to right direction.Thank you before hand.

FULL CLASS CODE.

```
package com.vegasslots.dialogs;

import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.vegasslots.R;

/**
 * Created by vladimirarevhstayna on 12/24/15.
 */
public class LevelUpDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "_LevelUpDialog";
    private ImageView coin_1;
    private ImageView coin_2;
    private ImageView coin_3;
    private ImageView coin_4;
    private ImageView coin_5;
    private ImageView coin_6;
    private ImageView coin_7;
    private ImageView coin_8;
    private ImageView coin_9;
    private ImageView coin_10;
    private ImageView coin_11;
    private ImageView coin_12;
    private ImageView coin_13;
    private ImageView coin_14;
    private ImageView coin_15;

    private CountDownTimer levelUpCountDownTimer;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //init our viewHolder of .
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_level_up_view, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        final RelativeLayout levelUpLightingLeft = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.levelUpLighting_left);
        RelativeLayout levelUpLightingRight = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.levelUpLighting_right);
        coin_1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        coin_2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView16);
        coin_3 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        coin_4 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
        coin_5 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
        coin_6 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
        coin_6 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
        coin_7 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        coin_8 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView15);
        coin_9 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView14);
        coin_10 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        coin_11 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        coin_12 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        coin_13 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
        coin_14 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        coin_15 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView13);

        view.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).setOnClickListener(this);
//
        levelUpLightingLeft.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotate_left));
        levelUpLightingRight.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotate_right));



        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.playTogether(

                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(coin_1, "translationX", 180, -90),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(coin_1, "translationY", 180, -90)
        );

        set.setDuration(200).start();

        levelUpCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(4000, 4000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "ON FINISH");
                if (isVisible()) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            }
        }.start();

        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

//        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#aa000000")));
//        getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        levelUpCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dismiss();
    }


}
```

Comment: are you animating an `ImageView` ?

Comment: yes i do animate the ImageView

Comment: thats might be the issue?

Comment: no, but if `ObjectAnimator` doesn't work (and it just **SHOULD** work with `"rotation"` property) you could use an `ImageView` with `scaleType = "matrix"` and animate the `Matrix` in `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`

Comment: hmmm interesting very interesting,can i have a piece of code as an answer?

Comment: dang this...i tried but still lags and same result:(

Comment: first just try: `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "rotation", 0, 360)` if it doesnt work try animating the `Matrix`

Comment: i tried both,i tried to rotate with object animator before and it did not work,now i tried with matrix,still same result...lags...i just pretty can't understand why its like that?According to official docs,all animations and rendering is controlled and used by GPU(processor) and i have being tested it on almost the most powerful devices like nexus 7.galaxy s 5,huawei p8 (octra core) and in docs they say if animation not proper,it might be the processor clock speed lack,but....please...does octra core with 1.3ghz is the lack?this is annoying me already...they can't even create normal property?

Comment: so your app must be doing something in the background, it just should work fine, btw the easiest is `android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator`

Comment: unfortunately nothing is done,as if i resize image to smaller,it works wonderfull,ill edit the question with full code

Answer (score 1):

I reduce the animation duration to half and it worked for some reasons!

```
android:duration="500"
```